# WPF colorAnimation border brush color throws 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement color animation on border brush with `Style.Triggers`.

The ViewModel changes the collection which each Border color is bounded.

I guess the UI elements are not initialized but the condition is fulfilled and then the exception is thrown:

> "Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'BorderBrush.Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Here the `View.cs.xaml` code:

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:SchemaNode}" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Border CornerRadius="40">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Closed}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Outline}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                  Command="{Binding OnDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding GlobalId}"/>
        </Border.InputBindings>
        <Border.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextActions}" Width="150" Placement="Mouse">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helper:ContextAction}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Border.ContextMenu>
        <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="360"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Outline}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Located}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="LocatedBeginStoryBoard">
                                    <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Duration="0:0:0.4"
                                                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                            To="5"/>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                                                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                            BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                                                            To="5"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
                                                        To="White"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LocatedBeginStoryBoard"/>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Image Height="50"
                   Width="50" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource imagePathToImageConverter}}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding OnDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding GlobalId}"/>
                </Image.InputBindings>
            </Image>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Hopefully I have provided enough code do resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the `BorderBursh` you bind via `Outline` is not a `SolidColorBrush` but a `GradientBrush` or simply unassigned and therefore doesn't have a `Color` property.

You can test this by assigning a `SolidColorBrush` (directyl or via style).

```xml
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style.Setters>
    <!-- etc -->
```

[image: Proof of concept]

Comment: Outline is SolidColorBursh, I tried your solution but I get exception with additional information : "Cannot animate 'BorderBrush.Color' on an immutable object instance."

Comment: Then you are probably (as the error suggest) using a frozen (immutable) instance or a static brush (e.g. Brushes.Red) - you need a separate instance that isn't frozen.

Comment: Thank you. The BorderBrush binding must be set in Style.Setters instead in the Border tag as a property.